# vsftpd: 500 OOPS: could not bind listening IPv4 socket

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, ssl, vsftpd

I will use vsftpd as a ftp server. I did all changes on /etc/vsftpd.conf.

These  changes are (according to digitalocean):

```
anonymous_enable=NO
write_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
```

More here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-configure-vsftpd-to-use-ssl-tls-on-an-ubuntu-vps

I'v also created a ssl certificate file. (not necessary but recommended)

Still getting :

> 500 OOPS: could not bind listening IPv4 socket

Note:

> pam_service_name=vsftpd

Netstat:

```
netstat -pan|grep :21;
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30694/vsftpd
```

Comment: Just curious... why not just use SFTP?

Answer (score 1):

Much probably you have `/etc/xinetd.d/ftp` `enabled` AND pointing to `/usr/sbin/vsftpd` and in `/etc/vsftpd.conf` you have `listen=YES`.

Simply change it to `listen=NO`. The `listen=YES` is for standalone, if you want vsftpd to be always active then you'll have to disabled it in the `xinetd` config.

Answer (score 0):

you might need a LISTEN line:
LISTEN=YES

UPDATE: From your netstat result, it seems that the vsftpd is actually running and it is associated with 0.0.0.0:21. So port (21) on all interfaces. This might be a warning that one of the interfaces is not accepting the bind request. Can you test the ftp server? Do you get a directory listing?

UPDATE 2: Is SELinux activated? Can you please try to login as passive and as active and check if one works?... These things have a history with ftp. Another thing to look out for is whether the home directory of the user account used for login is actually owned by the user. vsftpd is very sensitive when it comes to permissions.

Comment: Sorry, already have.

Comment: do you use wrappers? i think xinetd can cause this as well... Sometimes some work on the wrappers is needed. It might help if you want to check to see if the port is taken by another service such as another ftp server by netstat.

Comment: Weird.. I wrote ftp.mysiteaddress and browser asked me to login with user info. I did but i got "No data received" error.